# SQL query feels inefficient - how can I improve it?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using the SQL code below in SQLite to get a list of trades from a table containing trades and then combining it with total portfolio value on the day from a holdings table that has position and price data for a set of instruments.

The holdings table has about 150000 records and the trades table has about 1700

```
SELECT t.*, (SELECT     p.adjclose FROM prices AS p
                WHERE   t.instrument = p.instrument
                        AND p.date = "2013-02-28 00:00:00") as close,
            su.mv as mv
            FROM trades AS t
left outer join 
      (SELECT h.date, SUM(h.price * h.position) as mv FROM holdings AS h
        WHERE h.portfolio = "usequity" 
        AND h.date >= "2013-01-11 00:00:00"
        AND h.date <= "2013-02-2"
        GROUP BY h.date) as su
     ON t.date = su.date         
   WHERE t.portname = "usequity"
                AND t.date >= "2013-01-11 00:00:00"
                AND t.date <= "2013-02-28 00:00:00";
```

Running the SQL code returns

```
[2014-12-01 19:21:00] 123 row(s) retrieved starting from 1 in 572/627 ms
```

Which seems really slow for a small dataset. Both tables are indexed on instrument and date.

I don't know how to index the table `su` on the fly so I'm not sure how to improve this code. Any help greatly appreciated.

## EDIT

explain query plan shows

```
selectid,order,from,detail
1,0,0,"SEARCH TABLE holdings AS h USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (portfolio=?) (~7 rows)"
1,0,0,"USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY"
0,0,0,"SCAN TABLE trades AS t (~11111 rows)"
0,1,1,"SEARCH SUBQUERY 1 AS su USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (date=?) (~3 rows)"
0,0,0,"EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 2"
2,0,0,"SEARCH TABLE prices AS p USING INDEX p1 (instrument=? AND date=?) (~9 rows)"
```

Comment: Show the [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) output.

Comment: hi @CL. added. thanks for looking at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lookup on `prices` is fast (it's using the index for both columns).

You could create a temporary table for the `su` subquery and add an index to that, but the `AUTOMATIC INDEX` shows that the database is already doing this.

The lookup on `holdings` is done with a temporary index; you should create an explicit index for that. (An index on both `portfolio` and `date` would be even more efficient.)

You could avoid the need for a temporary table by looking up the values from `holdings` dynamically, like you're already doing for the closing price (but this might not be an improvement if there are many trades on the same day):

```
SELECT t.*,
       (SELECT p.adjclose
        FROM prices AS p
        WHERE p.instrument = t.instrument
          AND p.date = '2013-02-28 00:00:00'
       ) AS close,
       (SELECT SUM(h.price * h.position)
        FROM holdings AS h
        WHERE h.portfolio = 'usequity'
          AND h.date = t.date
       ) AS mv
FROM trades AS t
WHERE t.portname = 'usequity'
  AND t.date BETWEEN '2013-01-11 00:00:00'
                 AND '2013-02-28 00:00:00';
```